# Как посмотреть время /дату последнего посещения пользователя telegram

Tags: c#, telegram

Можно ли посмотреть с помощью Telegram API время когда пользователь telegram был в сети последний раз?
А то есть такие у которых включена last seen privacy и тогда просто написано «last seen recently». А вот узнать конкретное время у таких можно ли?

Comment: Невозможно посмотреть время и дату последнего посещение в telegram api.